# Markers failing to show up in Leaflet JS

Tags: javascript, leaflet

For Some reason none of the markers are apearing on the webpage but the map renders just fine. I would appreciate some help in finding out what is my error.

index.html

```
<div id="mapid"></div>
<style>
  #mapid {
    height: 750px;
}

</style>
```

app.js

```
function controller($scope, $state) {


var map = L.map('mapid', {
    worldCopyJump: true,

}).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
var rmLight = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3']
}).addTo(map);

var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);

}
```

Comment: Do you  have any errors in your console?  A simple plunk with your code is working fine...the pop up is showing.  https://plnkr.co/edit/4KhOyBNTMnkkg2Gi9Tee?p=preview

Comment: nope none - in fact circles and polylines also show up just fine

Comment: Could be css.  Can you inspect the source and check to see if its added?  Maybe see if you can find this class  "leaflet-marker-icon".

Comment: thanks, yeah there was an error with the importing of images thank you!

Comment: I will move the answer to the comment...please accept it and close!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good per the plunker in the comment.

Also check the source to see if the element is there and just not showing up due to a css or image problem.